# Knight's tour from all starting positions

Tags: graphs

Is it true that for all $n\geq 5$, there is a knight's tour of an $n\times n$ chessboard beginning at every square?

For example, is it correct, that there is no solution for a $5\times5$ board,
with start position $(5,4)$?

Comment: I've tried my given example. With no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) links to several useful papers. According to the paper [Solution of the knight’s Hamiltonian path problem on chessboards](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166218X9200170Q/1-s2.0-0166218X9200170Q-main.pdf?_tid=39b7545e-9261-11e4-af36-00000aacb361&acdnat=1420190880_39b5e22dfd96099f2834cd37955bd07a), there is no such tour; see Theorem 3.1(ii). They show that a knight's tour on the 5x5 board always starts or ends at a corner. It's also easy to see that both endpoint squares have the same color. Since the (5,4) square has a different color than the corners, no knight's tour starts at (5,4).